# VBA HTTP Request showing runtime error in different system

Tags: excel, vba, http, xmlhttprequest

I am facing error for my VBA(HTTP Request) code. while in my another system it is working fine.

**system(windows-8 /office-365):** Problem (runtime error:'-2147024809 (80070057)': The Parameter is incorrect.)

**system(windows-10 /office-16):** No Problem

References are same in both systems.

Please help me..!!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ku57.png)

Here is the Code:

```
Dim cook As String
Dim body1 As String
Dim xmlhttp As Object

Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
cook = Worksheets("Action").Range("I2").Value
body1 = Worksheets("Action").Range("I3").Value

URL = "https://trade.xxxxxxx.in/ITSStreamer/streamer/UserManagementServlet"
xmlhttp.Open "POST", URL, False
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Host", "trade.xxxxxxx.in"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Connection", "keep-alive"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Length", "700"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Origin", "https://trade.xxxxxxx.in"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Referer", "https://trade.xxxxxxx.in/NEWITS/InterfaceToValidateToken.do?"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.9"
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cook

xmlhttp.send body1

Debug.Print xmlhttp.ResponseText
```

Comment: please indicate on which line error occurs.

Comment: Please check what `cook` is if it fails. The error occurs if `cook` is an empty string in `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Cookie", cook`.

Comment: I checked Cook. the value is not empty (it contains=_ga=GA1.2.1569692012.1540233325; _gid=GA1.5.184220124.1545334131; _gat=1; JSESSIONID=965....). adding to this Error comming at the time of "xmlhttp.send body1". Same code is working on another laptop as mention on my problem statements. what you think.. is there any issue related with system config..?

Comment: I cannot reproduce that behavior using Office 365. But if `xmlhttp.send body1` throws that error, then `body1` must be the reason. I know that lower versions sometimes tried variables after `xmlhttp.send` using default `ByRef` mode, which fails. So try `xmlhttp.send (body1)`. Note the parentheses which forces `body1` using `ByVal`.

Comment: Axel: you are great... Thanks a lot..!! It's Working for me.. Thanks man..